# Unable to get result when making post or get call to 3rd party website with process diagram on jbpm Docker version

Tags: jbpm

I have created a task to make post call onto 3rd party website , where I have a API url, auth-basic,username,password,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', method: post , and have a body to post

How, should I fill the Data Assignments part for rest call in Jbpm docker version, Please help me

I tried assigning data of post call through different Data Assignments , like in image

but I am unabe to understand wher to pass body , how should I assign correctly in order to data get posted[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6MB8.png)